# Position of “in accordance with” in negative sentence affect meaning of the sentence

Tags: grammar, word-order

I find that the position of “in accordance with + noun” in a negative sentence affects the meaning of the whole sentence.

For example:

- Our company did not supply goods to country yy in accordance with the law.

(Here, the adverb “not” modifies “in accordance with ...” and they together modify the verb “supply”. Rephrase the sentence => (1) Our company did not in accordance with the law supply goods to country yy. - rephrased sentence #1)

v.s.

- In accordance with the law, our company did not supply goods to country yy.

(Here, “In accordance with ...” seems to modify the adverb “not” and they together modify the verb “supply”. Rephrase the sentence => (2) Our company in accordance with the law did not supply goods to country yy. - rephrased sentence #2)

It is clear that the meaning of rephrased sentence #1 is completely different from rephrased sentence #2

Is my finding/analysis correct?

Comment: Isn't 'He did not give sensibly' of the same structure (and a lot easier to analyse)? And the positive counterparts, 'Sensibly, he gave' and 'He gave sensibly' are both totally acceptable. // Admittedly, 'sensibly' switches between an evaluative and manner adverb (traditional senses of 'adverb') whereas 'in accordance with the law' remains a manner adverb.

Comment: By the way, you will find "in compliance with the law" much more frequently. Placement of "in accordance with" that can change the meaning from: **we did not supply/ it was illegal** to **we did not supply/it was legal** In accordance with can only modify the verb.

Comment: I think the first one could be read three ways, and that's bad. It could be taken to mean "We didn't do it because it's not legal" or "We didn't do it legally" or "We did it but not legally." The second version seems clear to me.

Comment: They are read differently because of the use of, or lack, of commas. The two sentences in example one could be made to have the same meaning as in example two by adding a few commas. - Our company did not supply goods to country yy, in accordance with the law. - Our company did not, in accordance with the law, supply goods to country yy.

Comment: @Lambie  Google has 184 000 000 results for "in accordance with the law" and 38 000 000 for "in compliance with the law".  I'd say "in accordance with the law" is the phrase used more frequently.